# php array data into list items

Tags: php, arrays

I have an *array data* that shows *data*, but I want to use it in list items e.g. `ul` and `li` tags but I don't know the exact way how can I do it here is the sample that I want may be using `while` or `foreach` loop

```
<ul>
    <li>Demo Item 1</li>
    <li>Demo Description 1</li>
    <li>http://demo-site.com/1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Demo Item 2</li>
    <li>Demo Description 2</li>
    <li>http://demo-site.com/2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Demo Item 3</li>
    <li>Demo Description 3</li>
    <li>http://demo-site.com/3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Demo Item 4</li>
    <li>Demo Description 4</li>
    <li>http://demo-site.com/4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Demo Item 5</li>
    <li>Demo Description 5</li>
    <li>http://demo-site.com/5</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://mywebsite-addr/stats.xml');
$parsed_results_array = array();
foreach($xml as $entry) {
    foreach($entry->match as $item) {
        // $parsed_results_array[] = json_decode(json_encode($item), true);
        $items['title'] = (string) $item->opponent->name;
        $items['description'] = (string) $item->result;
        $items['link'] = (string) $item->url;
        $items['time'] = (string) $item->date;
        $parsed_results_array[] = $items;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($parsed_results_array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Here is the *array data* that may help you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Demo Item 1
            [description] => Demo Description 1
            [link] => http://demo-site.com/1
            [time] => Wed 15 Jun 2016, 11:30 PM EDT
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Demo Item 2
            [description] => Demo Description 2
            [link] => http://demo-site.com/2
            [time] => Wed 15 Jun 2016, 10:00 PM EDT
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Demo Item 3
            [description] => Demo Description 3
            [link] => http://demo-site.com/4
            [time] => Wed 15 Jun 2016, 12:45 AM EDT
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Demo Item 4
            [description] => Demo Description 4
            [link] => http://demo-site.com/4
            [time] => Tue 14 Jun 2016, 11:45 PM EDT
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => Demo Item 5
            [description] => Demo Description 5
            [link] => http://demo-site.com/5
            [time] => Tue 14 Jun 2016, 10:00 PM EDT
        )

)
```

Comment: We are not a free coding service, please show us what you have tried in order to get the desired output and include any errors you might have gotten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ( $parsed_results_array as $arrayKey => $values ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>' . $values['title'] . '</li>';
    echo '<li>' . $values['description'] . '</li>';
    echo '<li>' . $values['link'] . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: There's other ways to get your badges

Answer (score 1):

templating alternative :

```
<?php
    // Some nice php code here ...
?>

<?php foreach( $parsed_results_array as $result ): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $result as $data ): ?>
    <li><?php echo $data ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach ?>    

<?php
    // Some other php code there ...
?>
```

Comment: FYI the `<?=` is special syntax that doesn't work everywhere out of the box and requires enabling in php.ini. I always stick to `<?php` for portability.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this without creating extra array:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://mywebsite-addr/stats.xml');
$parsed_results_array = array();

foreach($xml as $entry) {
    foreach($entry->match as $item) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>' . (string) $item->opponent->name . '</li>';
        echo '<li>' . (string) $item->result . '</li>';
        echo '<li>' . (string) $item->url . '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `(string)` necessary here and what is its role here  ?? please remove `$parsed_results_array = array();` as its doing nothing here i suppose...

Comment: as you know (string) is used for typecast.

Comment: Yes i know but i am asking what it its role in simple `echo value` ??

Comment: @PraveenKumar read entire tutorial here carefully:  http://www.techflirt.com/php/php-type-casting.html , you will get all your answers

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need either array, but at least drop this line

```
$parsed_results_array[] = $items;
```

And replace it with

```
echo "
<ul>
<li>$items[title]</li>
<li>$items[description]</li>
<li>$items[link]</li>
</ul>
";
```